# How can I cross reference a subfigure in an external document?

Tags: cross-referencing, mdpi

How do you cross reference a figure (with multiple subfigures) in an external latex file? I am currently using `xr` package and `cleveref` package to do it but I am constantly getting an error as shown below.

```
! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
```

Below is the setting I am using in the `main.tex` file. The required files for the custom document class can be found at

http://img.mdpi.org/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20170619

```
\documentclass[remotesensing,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{mdpi} 

\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother 
\articlenumber{x}
\doinum{10.3390/------}
\pubvolume{xx}
\pubyear{2017}
\copyrightyear{2017}
\externaleditor{Academic Editor: name}
\history{Received: date; Accepted: date; Published: date}

\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[ext-]{externaldocument}
\newcommand{\RE}[1]{\Re\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\IM}[1]{\Im\left\{#1\right\}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
\let\oldhat\hat
\renewcommand{\hat}[1]{\oldhat{\mathbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\newcommand{\w}{\omega}
\newcommand{\FT}[1]{\mathscr{F}\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\iFT}[1]{\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{#1\}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Title{Title example}
\Author{author 1}
\AuthorNames{author }
\address{
$^{1}$ \quad address 1 \\
$^{2}$ \quad address 2}
\corres{Correspondence: author1@gmail.com}
\abstract{blahblah}
\keyword{keyword1}


\begin{document}
\cref{ext-fig:example}
\end{document}
```

In the external latex file, `externaldocument.tex`,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newcommand{\RE}[1]{\Re\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\IM}[1]{\Im\left\{#1\right\}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
\let\oldhat\hat
\renewcommand{\hat}[1]{\oldhat{\mathbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\p}{\partial}
\newcommand{\w}{\omega}
\newcommand{\FT}[1]{\mathscr{F}\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\iFT}[1]{\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{#1\}}




\title{external document}


\author[1]{author 1}
\author[2]{author 2}
\affil[1]{affil 1}
\affil[2]{affil 2}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\renewcommand{\theequation}{S\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}


\begin{figure}[htp!]
 \centering
 \subfigure[example1]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
 \subfigure[example2]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
  \subfigure[example3]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
 \subfigure[example4]
   {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}}
 \caption{main caption.}
 \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}





\end{document}
```

Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your `externaldocument.tex` can't be compiled because of the missing figure and the `H` specifier for floats. After correcting this, I get the correct reference

Comment: Especially I don't get the error reported...

Comment: You omitted the `\documentclass` line in the main file. Did you perhaps omit something else, which could be the reason for the error?

Comment: Thank you Christian and Mike. I think the problem is the custom documentclass I am using since the cross-referencing works if I use the usual `documentclass[a4paper]{article}` in the *main.tex*. I changed the question so that the error I get can be reproduced. Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: @acoustica a hint: start the names of people you are talking to with an `@` (e.g. @Christian Hupfer and @Mike) . This way they will be notified of your new comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `hyperref`  before `cleverref` in *externaldocumnet.tex* should solve you problem.

The reason: The `mdpi` class loads `hyperref` and that redefines a lot of macros for cross-referencing. This includes macros written to the *.aux* file. Here additional parameters are added.

`cleverref` supports `hyperref`. This means it expects those additional parameters. But they are missing in the *externaldocument.aux* file, since it was compiled without hyperref.

Adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble of *externaldocumnet.tex* solves this problem. This must be done before `\uspackage{cleverref}`, otherwise you'll get undefined references.